# java overloaded method invocation order by an object at runtime

Tags: java, oop

Consider the following class hierarchy:

```
class A {
    compute(int a) {
        compute(a, 1);
    }

    compute(int a, int b) {
        // do some things
    }
}


class B extends A {
    compute(int a, int b) {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

if I initialize a B object like following using a A reference:

```
A foo = new B();
```

if I call:

```
foo.compute(1)
```

then, inside this method call, it will call class A's `compute(int, int)` or call class B's `compute(int, int)` ?

Any citation's from official java documentation?

Comment: Well, it's `B.compute(int, int)`, because that has overridden `A.compute(int, int)`. But why don't you try it?

Comment: see: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431185/what-is-the-use-of-java-virtual-method-invocation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431185/what-is-the-use-of-java-virtual-method-invocation)

Answer (score 0):

i would guess you are a C++ programmer. The behavior you're pointing do happen in C++ when you don't define the `compute(int, int)` function as `virtual`.

C++ designers are always looking for extreme performance, and so the non-`virtual` method calls of an object are defined at compile time, to avoid an  additional reference to a function pointer in its `vtable`, aka the table of virtual functions that it has.

If that's the case, let me tell you that in Java, all methods are implicitly defined as `virtual` in C++ terms.  That is: for a given object any method called is always the one belonging to the object that was constructed, not to the variable that references it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any citation upfront but let me take a shot at explaining what will happen.

We have

`A foo = new B();`

Here the reference type of foo is `A`. The object being instantiated is of type `B`.

Note that this statement could get compiled only if object `B` satisfies the is-a relationship with `A`. Since `B extends A`, `B` satisfies the is-a relationship with `A`.

The methods that could be invoked by foo are based on the reference type. Hence, foo can only invoke methods which are declared/defined in type of `A`. The actual method being invoked is based on the object type. Since the object referenced by `foo` is of type `B`, the method on object `B` is invoked. Hence, it is `B.compute(int,int)` that is being invoked.

Answer (score 0):

The method invoked will be `B.compute(int, int)`, which you can easily find by trying it.

---

Since you asked for documentation describing why this is, I will provide it. But it's not very easy to follow.

This is described in [JLS Sec 15.12.4. Run-Time Evaluation of Method Invocation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4).

Recall that the method invocation in question is `compute(a, 1);`

> **15.12.4.1. Compute Target Reference (If Necessary)**

The method invocation is of the form *`MethodName`*, and it is non-static, so the following case applies:

> Otherwise, let T be the enclosing type declaration of which the method is a member, and let n be an integer such that T is the n'th lexically enclosing type declaration of the class whose declaration immediately contains the method invocation. The target reference is the n'th lexically enclosing instance of this.

So we know our target reference. This is a long-winded way of saying that we're going to invoke the method on `this`.

> **15.12.4.2. Evaluate Arguments**

This is trivial, since the arguments are `int`s.

> **15.12.4.3. Check Accessibility of Type and Method**

Yeah, the type and method are accessible.

> **15.12.4.4. Locate Method to Invoke**

The invocation mode is `virtual`, as described in [Sec 15.12.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.3). Hence this applies:

> If the invocation mode is interface or virtual, then S is initially the actual run-time class R of the target object.

Notice that if you were to write `System.out.println(getClass())` immediately before the `compute(a, 1)` line, it would print out `B`, not `A` when invoked in the way shown in the question. Hence the run-time class `R` is `B`, so `S` is `B` also.

Also:

> Let X be the compile-time type of the target reference of the method invocation.

`X` is `A`.

Then:

> class S contains a declaration for a method named m with the same descriptor

and

> the invocation mode is `virtual`, and the declaration in `S` overrides `X.m` (§8.4.8.1), then the method declared in `S` is the method to be invoked, and the procedure terminates.

So, the method declared in `B` is invoked.

---

This is pretty heavy reading, and, quite honestly, you don't need to know it in this much detail. This is the first time I've actually bothered to pick through that bit of the spec.

The simple rule to remember is: if the method is overridden in a subclass, that's the one that gets invoked.