# cost comparison of run-time polymorphism in c++ vs java

Tags: java, c++, polymorphism

I often see people complaining about virtual function cost in C++. but same people dont say anything negative about runtime polymorohism in java.

if i have to develop a runtime in c++ which hosts applications on it which are also developed in c++, i would take the following approach:

1. have base classes with virtual methods, which represent an 'abstract' application. this is runtime's view of the application. the app developer inherits the base classes and compiles his application into a dynamically loadable shared library.
2. have base classes with virtual methods, which represents a 'service' from the runtime. the runtime implements those services. the application uses these services through these interface classes. the runtime loads the application dynamic library and initializes the application with an implementation object of its service.

now both application and runtime have each other's handles and invoke each other using virtual method calls. Yes, there is a cost involved but this also gives us decoupling of app from the runtime. if no virtual methods, the app will always have link time dependency with the runtime.

Now consider a similar case in Java. Java also has interfaces which need to be implemented, and there must be a similar cost for runtime polymorphism involved.

*is my understanding about java runtime polymorhism correct?*

And if there is a cost involved with java also, why always c++ gets the angry comments that "Ohh there is virtual function cost, and the approach which uses virtual function to decouple parts of the application is **certainly bad**". where do these people go in case Java? they dont say anything.

My question is how to handle such comments? what rational arguments can be given in favour of C++?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for programmers.

Comment: Handling virtual method calls in Java is incredibly cheap.  Handling interface calls is rather more expensive, depending on how well the JVM caches lookups.  C++ suffers from a significant performance hit on all virtual calls because it allows multiple inheritance, which Java does not.

Answer (score 4):

Java is basically designed completely end-to-end to speed up that precise scenario:

- objects are always accessed by reference (so that you can mix and match different types within the same class hierarchy. You can make an array of Fruit objects, and it can naturally store Banana objects as well. This doesn't affect performance, it but it makes code using run-time polymorphism easier and simpler to write.
- It uses a garbage collector which allows objects to be moved around in memory after allocation, so that, even though an array just stores references, the referenced objects can be packed together in contiguous memory to minimize cache misses which would otherwise hurt performance badly
- The language is JIT'ed (or in some cases interpreted), so that at run-time, the JVM can look at a virtual call, and in many cases optimize it into a regular function call.

C++ doesn't have all this machinery: having to store and access objects by reference/pointer in C++ is both tedious and error-prone, but also inefficient (the objects pointed to by the members of an array won't be allocated next to each others, so accessing each object will likely result in a cache miss).
And when the C++ compiler comes across a virtual call, it usually can't determine which function is going to be called, so it can't optimize away the virtual-ness. And when it can't do that, it also can't inline the call (which C++ compilers rely heavily on for performance).

But on the other hand C++ doesn't *need* to rely on this as much either. C++ instead gives you powerful static polymorphism, which can *often* be used instead, eliminating the overhead completely.

So yes, run-time polymorphism, with virtual calls and with inheritance often *is* more expensive in C++, because it doesn't have the extensive plumbing necessary to speed it up.
But at the same time, C++ also makes run-time polymorphism more difficult to use, *and* in many cases it provides alternatives you can use instead.

People often claim that "the cost of a virtual call is just a pointer indirection", but it has many subtle costs, as hinted at above: it inhibits function inlining, and it requires objects to be handled using reference semantics, which again affects memory locality which hurts the CPU cache utilization. It has wide-ranging effects, and Java is effectively designed from scratch to compensate for as many of these as possible. C++ isn't, and in most cases, has to take the performance hit when run-time polymorphism is used.

Of course, it is likely *also* true that typical C++ programmers are just more concerned about performance than Java programmers are (you don't often hear Java programmers discuss their code's CPU cache utilization, for example)

> If i have to develop a runtime in c++ which hosts applications on it which are also developed in c++, i would take the following approach <...>

Please don't. As said above, C++ code generally doesn't, and shouldn't, use runtime polymorphism to solve every problem. In Java, it is effectively the only tool you have access to, and it is used, and must be used, and should be used very extensively. In C++, it is one tool in an entire toolbox of options. And when alternatives are available, it is often best avoided.

> there is a cost involved but this also gives us decoupling of app from the runtime. if no virtual methods, the app will always have link time dependency with the runtime.

And? Is there a problem in having such a link-time dependency? Are you going to swap out the app while it's running?

Comment: `And? Is there a problem in having such a link-time dependency?` so instead of just giving an sdk to the developer i will also give runtime implementation lib to him so that his app does not have undefined symbols. it is like the runtime is a library and the application is the exe which is linking with and loading the runtime, just the reverse.  `Are you going to swap out the app while it's running?` yes, there is a possibility of runtime upgrading.

Comment: `The language is JIT'ed (or in some cases interpreted), so that at run-time, the JVM can look at a virtual call, and in many cases optimize it into a regular function call.` so in this case Java seems to be better than C++ as it can optimize away the virtual function overhead.

Comment: @weima I don't follow the first point. Undefined symbols? What do they have to do with anything? And why does a link-time dependency imply unefined symbols? And for swapping out a library while an app is running, you generally don't need runtime polymorphism. You just ned a library boundary and some thoughtful design. On the second point, yes, for the things Java is designed for, Java is better than C++. Just like Python is better than Fortran at the things Python was designed for. And a Skoda is better than the Space Shuttle for the things the Skoda was designed for. :)

Comment: say application wants to send Message through the runtime. and application calls a non-virtual method defined in the runtime for it. if i dont link the implementation of that method with my application, my application will have unresolved symbol. since the implementation of that method will reside inside a class of runtime, application needs link time dependency on runtime. else symbol remains unresolved. if i do `ldd -r` on the application library it will show undefined symbol. the symbol may be resolved when i run the application with the runtime.

Comment: *"C++ doesn't have all this machinery: having to store and access objects by reference/pointer in C++ is both tedious and error-prone, but also inefficient (the objects pointed to by the members of an array won't be allocated next to each others, so accessing each object will likely result in a cache miss)"* -- How does this differ from Java (other than Java is strongly typed so references are trustworthy)?

Comment: @HotLicks Java is garbage-collected, and most garbage collectors implement heap allocation effectively by slicing bytes off a preallocated stack. So if you make N heap allocs in a row, they'll be located contiguously by default. And even if they're not, the GC will typically move objects around in memory when collecting, giving it another opportunity to move the allocations next to each others to improve locality. With heap allocs in C++, you're effectively given an allocation at an arbitrary address

Comment: @jalf - That it totally separate from the issue of polymorphism and not particularly true.  Getting objects allocated contiguously in heap assumes a copying GC (and several high-performance Java GCs are not copying) and assumes that the individual objects in the array are allocated back-to-back vs having other objects allocated in-between.  And keep in mind that a well-managed C++ heap will also be reasonably likely to allocate subsequent objects next to each other.

Comment: @HotLicks it is separate from polymorphism yes, but it affects the performance of using polymorphism (In Java, you can allocate an array of abstract Fruit objects, and the actual objects will likely be allocated contiguously. In C++, with non-polymorphic types, you'd just store the objects by value in your array, but with polymorphism you're forced to store an array of pointers to separately-allocated objects). The point is Java is designed to provide the tools to handle this scenario (even if some implementations may not use them to the full extent).

Comment: Like I said, there are several reasons why your assumptions are not completely correct.

Comment: @HotLicks I didn't make any assumptions, I pointed out factual reasons why Java has the capability to mitigate the performance hit, and why the options for a typical C++ compiler are much more limited. Any *assumptions* in there are your own.

Answer (score 1):

I fear that writing an answer here will be futile, as there MUST be an answer here already.

Without being too "language warry" about it, I think people who use Java aren't necessarily QUITE so focused on performance as C++ programmers, which may reflect a part of the notional difference between "Oh, we'll have to worry about the overhead".

There is certainly some overhead between a virtual and non-virtual function [1] - and a non-virtual function can sometimes be inlined in places where the virtual version can't. But given the other choices (using a switch or if-statement to decide what to do) are rarely good either, and with a bit of good design (don't design something that calls a virtual function to add two integers together, if it's going to be called in a tight loop - because the overhead is going to be fairly significant - use a function that knows there are hundreds or thousands of integers to add together - if possible of course).

[1] The overhead consists of an indirect read of the `this` pointer to find the vtable, and then calling the function at offset X from that. The main overhead tends to be that "more registers" are being used, which can have a negative effect on the efficiency of the code.

Comment: what is the Java;s mechanism of dispatching calls in run-time polymorphism. for c++ we all know the vtable approach. which is not very much discussed is Java's approach.

Comment: Don't know myself. I'm not a professional/experienced Java programmer (I have written a couple of hundred lines, but that is hardly scratching the surface). But this SO answer seems to imply that it's using a very similar functionality:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486160/java-virtual-methods

Comment: yes thanks. i saw that now.

Comment: the approach that i defined in my question, can we do better than that in c++ for such a scenario? in my mind that is the best that can be done.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between C++ and Java in using virtual methods is that a Java developer has no choice therefore a Java developer does not think about performance implications in this case.

Also the Java VM is designed to handle virtual calls. There is some performance implication of this but you can not measure it as you have no other way. Also newer VMs can also inline virtual methods during runtime.

In C++ you have a history. C++ comes from C and in the early days there was no dynamic linking. Over the time dynamic linking was added and this linking process had to be done in a compatible way. Adding virtual functions was then made in a way that should be compatible with this. Also the first C++ compiler were only preprocessors to C so that virtual functions had to be mapped to existing C structures.

Therefore I think that the performance implications of virtual functions in C++ is primary based on history.

Comment: thanks. so does it mean that if c++ had no legacy of C, the whole runtime polymorphism could be achieved in a different, more efficient way?

Comment: @weima - C has no (real) polymorphism (it barely has unimorphism).  The C++ mechanism probably could have been designed better, but at the time it was probably viewed as a hack that would be rarely used in performance-sensitive situations.

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple factors contributing to the difference in opinions you're seeing.

One factor is that the C++ crowd who's worried about the performance penalty of runtime polymorphism is likely to not be the same crowd as the people who'll be using runtime polymorphism gratuitously in Java.

Another factor is that when a project is in C++, it often means that there are some strict performance requirements. In those cases, programmers will anyway go to great lengths to adjust the input, the algorithms and the data structures to reduce dynamic bindings and help the compiler and the CPU predict and optimize the critical operations. In environments where Java is used, instead, it there are often requirements much more important than strict performance and, in those cases, runtime polymorphism is inevitable.

And another very important factor is that a C++ program is typically AOT compiled and the compiler cannot by default take advantage of a plethora of new information that comes up at runtime. A JVM, on the other hand, can employ the JIT compiler to make the native code of critical areas adapt in order to gain higher performance for the most probable outcomes. Frameworks of object-oriented languages tend to be very efficient in optimizing runtime binding.