# How does Java call object's function?

Tags: java, jvm

From what I read before, after `.java` file compiles to `.class` files, every object is simply `Object` after erasure. Such as

```
Foo f = new Foo();
```

Compiles to `.class` file, and decompile, it becomes:

```
Object f = new Foo();
```

So how does JRE call the function of an object when running? Where is the function stored in the memory? Inside the object? Or with a hierarchy of class structure and does lookup up the hierarchy?

Comment: _but every object is simply Object._ No...where did you read that?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Confusion with type erasure?

Comment: No... `Foo f = new Foo();` still has its' type information. I think you're confused with generics.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch maybe I need to rephrase it. I know every object still typed, but my question how does it do function lookup and where is the function stored?

Comment: In the class when the class was compiled (and then in the Object when the Object was instantiated)... try using [javap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html) on your `class` file.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't think there's any confusion.  The **compile-time** type declaration is not needed any more.  Once the compiler has determined that there are no type conflict errors, there's no difference between `Foo f` and `Object f`.

Comment: @ajb Yes, there is, especially if `Foo` appears in a method signature.

Comment: Someone please remove that tag `jrt` or make it a synonym to `jre`. **Please!**

Comment: @chrylis Maybe I wasn't clear.  What I meant was that after *every* source has been compiled (so that all that's left to do is run the program), there's no reason for the program to know whether a variable, parameter, or method return type was _declared_ as `Foo`, `Object`, or anything else.  That information doesn't need to be retained, as far as I know (unless it's somehow needed for reflection?).  I think that's what the OP is getting at, but I could have misunderstood the question.

Comment: @ajb That's incorrect. Method signatures are exposed in the `.class` file exactly as they're listed at compile time (with the exception of erasure of generic types), and Java needs them for both compile-time checking and runtime linking.

Comment: @chrylis OK, then.  Dynamic class loading was something I hadn't taken into consideration.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Java spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html) and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file)

> There are 10 basic sections to the Java Class File structure:
>
> - Magic Number: 0xCAFEBABE
> - Version of Class File Format: the minor and major versions of the class file
> - Constant Pool: Pool of constants for the class
> - Access Flags: for example whether the class is abstract, static, etc.
> - **This Class**: The name of the current class
> - **Super Class**: The name of the super class
> - Interfaces: Any interfaces in the class
> - Fields: Any fields in the class
> - **Methods**: Any methods in the class
> - Attributes: Any attributes of the class (for example the name of the sourcefile, etc.)

At run time, the type of the object is retrieved, its class file (or rather the [virtual method table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486160/java-virtual-methods)) is checked for an implementation of the method invoked. If that class doesn't have such an implementation, the parent class is checked (retrieved from super class entry), and so on, eventually failing if none is found.

Comment: So you mean the classes were not preloaded? Rather it checks the file on the disk every time?

Comment: @texasbruce The `.class` files contain the byte code for the methods. I believe it's up to the JVM to cache them or look them up every time. Depends on implementation (but let's be real).

Answer (score 1):

When you declare

```
Foo f;
```

at any point during `f`'s lifetime, it can be a reference to objects that aren't of type `Foo`.  The object type can be `Foo` *or any of its subclasses*.  Therefore, the object *must* store information about the actual ("runtime") type of the object, somewhere within each object.  (I believe this information is associated with the object itself, not with references to the object such as `f`.)  I don't know exactly what the format of this information looks like in JVM.  But in other compiled languages I've worked with, the type information includes a pointer to a vector of code addresses.  If the type `Foo` declares methods `method1()`, `method2()`, etc., then each one will be given an index number (and that number will be preserved for methods that are inherited or overridden in subclasses).  So calling a method means going to that vector and finding the function address for the given index.  This will work whether the actual run-time type is `Foo` or any subclass of `Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

**Example code:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Foo {
    public static void main() {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Object obj = new Object();
        foo.f();

        ArrayList<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
        ArrayList objList = new ArrayList();
    }

    public void f() {
    }
}
```

**Generated JVM instructions (**`javap -c Foo`**):**

```
public class Foo {
  public Foo();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return        

  public static void main();
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class Foo
       3: dup           
       4: invokespecial #3                  // Method "<init>":()V
       7: astore_0      
       8: new           #4                  // class java/lang/Object
      11: dup           
      12: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
      15: astore_1      
      16: aload_0       
      17: invokevirtual #5                  // Method f:()V
      20: new           #6                  // class java/util/ArrayList
      23: dup           
      24: invokespecial #7                  // Method java/util/ArrayList."<init>":()V
      27: astore_2      
      28: new           #6                  // class java/util/ArrayList
      31: dup           
      32: invokespecial #7                  // Method java/util/ArrayList."<init>":()V
      35: astore_3      
      36: return        

  public void f();
    Code:
       0: return        
}
```

As you can see, `Foo foo = new Foo();` gets translated to:

```
0: new           #2                  // class Foo
3: dup           
4: invokespecial #3                  // Method "<init>":()V
7: astore_0
```

while `Object obj = new Object();` turns into:

```
8: new           #4                  // class java/lang/Object
11: dup           
12: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
15: astore_1
```

`new` allocates memory for the object and stores a reference in the stack, `dup` creates a second reference in the stack, `invokespecial` calls the constructor (which is actually a method called `<init>`). Then, the instance is stored in a local variable with `astore_1`.

As for `ArrayList<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<Foo>();` and `ArrayList objList = new ArrayList();`, they compile to nearly the same thing:

```
28: new           #6                  // class java/util/ArrayList
31: dup           
32: invokespecial #7                  // Method java/util/ArrayList."<init>":()V
35: astore_3
```

One uses `astore_2` and the other one uses `astore_3`. That's because they are stored in different local variables. Other than that, the generated code is the same, which means that the JVM can't tell `Arraylist<Foo>` from `Arraylist`, which is what they call **type erasure**. However, it can very easily tell `Foo` from `Object`.

Comment: I love the smell of bytecode in the morning. Not enough answers take the time to delve into the low level! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your example is a [local variable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html). Local variables exist only within a function, and are not accessible to the outside world. As a result, there is no need for the compiler to store information about the variable in the classfile (this is *not* [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), which refers to losing information about parameterized types).

In the classfile, local variables are referenced as numbered slots within the [stack frame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.1). Thus, the bytecode operator `aload_0` retrieves the value in slot 0 (which will be `this` for instance methods) and puts it on the top of the operand stack, while `astore_1` takes the reference off the top of the operand stack and puts it in slot 1 of the frame.

Since the compiler knows the type of each slot in the frame, it can ensure that only the correct methods get called. The JVM provides an extra check: if you could modify the slot to contain an invalid object reference, the `invokevirtual` operation would fail.

While there's no need to store type information about local variables to run your program, there is a need to have that information for debugging. So you can give the compiler the `-g` switch, which causes it to put a [LocalVariableTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.13) in your classfile. This table contains the original name and type of each local variable.

If your decompiler is showing local variables as `Object`, it means one of two things: (1) the classfile was written without debugging information, or (2) the decompiler isn't smart enough to apply that information to the bytecode.

Answer (score -1):

if you take a look at the VM specification you will see that the code of each method for each class is stored in the class .class file. see this link [class file format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html)