# Analogy/Equivalence in C++ and Java

Tags: java, c++

Two things:

1.Are **Nested Classes** in Java like **Composition** in C++?

2.Are **Virtual functions** in C++ equivalent to **Function Overriding** in Java?

Comment: The C++ language has capabilities for nested classes.  They would both be composition in either language.  They are treated the same in both languages.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Java "nested classes" come in "inner class" and "static nested class" flavors.  C++ has no (non-manual) equivalent to "inner class".

Answer (score 2):

Nested classes in Java come in two flavors: Inner Classes and Static Nested Classes.

There is no direct equivalent of an Inner Class in C++.  If you want it, you need to do it manually, giving the "Inner Class" a pointer back to the outer class (either in every method as an argument, or stored within the "Inner Class").

A static nested class in Java is similar to declaring a class within a class in C++.

Composition in C++ is when an actual value of the composed class is stored within another class.  There are no class-value-types in Java, all Java class types are references, so there is no direct equivalent in Java.  Java "composition" is going to store references to the "sub-objects": this can be done in C++ via references, pointers or smart pointers.

C++ `virtual` methods are similar to non-`final` non-`static` methods in Java.  C++ non-virtual non-static methods have no real equivalent in Java (final methods are approximately equivalent, but more similar to `virtual` `final` methods in C++).  You can override a virtual function in C++ in ways somewhat similar to how you override a non-static non-final function in Java: for example, they both support covariant return types (they may disagree about what is covariant, however).  Some of the details are going to be different.

`static` methods in Java and C++ are similar.

(I am a C++ programmer, my knowledge of Java is almost entirely a matter of contrast: trust my statements about C++ far more than my statements about Java.)

Comment: C++ virtual is more close to Java's abstract class methods

Comment: @texas `virtual` != pure virtual.

Answer (score 1):

1. Both Java and C++ support nested classes and composition, and as per *Thomas Matthews'* comment: *"They are treated the same in both languages."*
2. In Java, *all* non-static methods are virtual by default (you can use `final` to make them non-virtual). In C++ you have to *explicitly* mark them `virtual` to be able to override them.

Answer (score 1):

1. Composition is a design term, nesting classes is a language mechanism (which may be used to implement composition). As Thomas Matthews mentioned in his comment, both languages support nested classes.
2. Non-static methods in Java behave polimorphically by default, i.e. unlike in C++ you don't use the `virtual` keyword to make a method virtual. This question has some good answers about how virtual methods work behind the scenes: [Java - Virtual Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486160/java-virtual-methods)

Answer (score 0):

1.) Java and C++ support nested classes. After all, in java a class can have an instance in another class's member data.

Composition is just having a wrapper class for other classes.

Like this example from wikipedia

```
class Pond{
private:
    std::vector<ducks*> myDucks;
}
```

2.) Virtual functions are functions that are defined in base classes in C++ for classes that inherit the parent class to define. `virtual` is required to overload the function in classes that inherit the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

Ad. 2. The method / virtual function in C ++ is:

1. Method with the default implementation;
2. It can be override in a derived class but it does not have to;
3. It can not be static, it is used to obtain polymorphism;
4. We can refer to the method by the base type for
   polymorphism;

Looking at the above, an analogous method for Java would be a method with the modifier "default" in the interface, available from version 8.

example:

```
public interface Foo {
   default String bar() {
      return "Foo.bar";
   }
}
```